# Lubuntu No Wifi & No Reboot/Shut Down

Tags: networking, wireless, lubuntu, reboot, restart

I'm pretty new to Linux and Ubuntu. I just installed the Lubuntu on my mother's old laptop to replace XP. But after the installation I was unable to connect to wireless network. For at least a week I've been hunting this forum and google for solutions but nothing seems to work. It works pretty well when wired to my router. 
Also when I do updates or installations of b43 whenever I have to restart or shut down it stays on a black screen or hangs on the Lubuntu logo with the dots. I usually have press the power button to shut it off fully. So I'm not even sure if the updates gets processed. Idk what to do I'm so lost right now. I will be grateful if someone can give me a solution. I would like to my moms laptop to be working as soon as possible(its a delayed mother's day gift)

ET : My results to "lspci -nn | grep 0280" are

06:05.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One 54g] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:4318] (rev 02)

ET: The Laptop is an Hp Pavilion DV4305us

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Welcome to askubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Please hook up the ethernet temporarily and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

If the latter isn't installed, that's fine, just continue.

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Detach the ethernet. Next, do:

```
sudo modprobe -r ssb
sudo modprobe -r b43
sudo modprobe b43
```

Does the wireless come to life?

You may be able to resolve the shutdown issue with a complete update:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After it completes, does it reboot as expected?

Comment: I have tried doing that many times but when it says to reboot or shut down I always get stuck on the lubuntu logo or a black screen. It never fully reboots/ shuts down, I end up having to do a cold shutting by press the power button.

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: HI, I did but my computer doesn't shut down/reboot very well, should I still try those commands?

Comment: Yes, please do.

Comment: Hi, I tried the sudo modprobe codes. No luck with wifi, should I go ahead with the updates?

Comment: also I just realised I downloaded the 15. something version of Lubuntu, would it be better is I install the 14.10 version?

Comment: Yes, update; the fix for your shutdown issue may be one of the updates. No, do not install an _older_ Ubuntu version.

Comment: I did the update, but still does not shut down

Comment: Are you running Gnome? Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/616571/laptop-doesnt-power-off-on-shutdown-after-upgrade-to-15-04-and-gnome-3-16

Comment: I don't believe so, I literally only installed lubuntu

Comment: Sorry about my mis-step. Of course, you are running LXDE and not Gnome. Sorry. If you try to shut down from the terminal: `sudo halt -p`does it shut down? If not, are there informative messages in the terminal?

Comment: I tried that, still does not shut down. Some quick message comes up but it does not seem like an error message.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am not a shutdown expert. I will be happy to troubleshoot the wireless when shutdown is fixed.